# HighCharts fitting long Y-axis labels

Tags: highcharts

I have some big vertical(Y) axis label names. When they are displayed, they shrink the size of the actual chart and reading them becomes confusing.
Here is the image:

[image]

As can be seen in the image, the labels are unaligned. How to make them properly align?

Here are the chart options I am using:

```
{
  "plotOptions": {
    "series": {
      "pointPadding": 0,
      "borderWidth": 0
    }
  },
  "chart": {
    "height": "50%"
  },
  "rangeSelector": {
    "selected": 1
  },
  "title": {
    "text": "Index EOD Analysis"
  },
  "tooltip": {
    "split": true
  },
  "yAxis": [
    {
      "labels": {
        "align": "right",
        "x": -3
      },
      "title": {
        "text": "OHLC"
      },
      "height": "60%"
    },
    {
      "labels": {
        "align": "right",
        "x": -3
      },
      "height": "20%",
      "top": "60%",
      "title": {
        "text": "FII Consolidated PCR"
      }
    },
    {
      "labels": {
        "align": "right",
        "x": -3
      },
      "height": "20%",
      "top": "80%",
      "title": {
        "text": "Net Seller Index"
      }
    }
  ],
  "series": [
    {...}
  ]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can increase a width of the labels:

```
"yAxis": [...,
    {
        ...
        "title": {
            ...,
            style: {
                width: '200px'
            }
        }
    }
]
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/eb4g6rtc/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.title.style